# Cat REALLY wants to leave his "safe" room after 1 day at our house

Tags: cats, adoption

We got a Birman cat a day ago and he just sits at the door of his safe room at meows a majority of the time I'm sitting in his room. He will also come to me and wait for me to notice him and then walk to the door and start meowing. The afternoon that he came home with us he seemed incredibly inquisitive and we decided to let him out, 10 minutes later he was cowering in the dark corner of our bathroom so we put him back in the safe room. I am wondering if I should let him out or keep him in here?

Comment: There's no one definite answer to this question. I would close all doors and only let him out into the hall and the safe room to avoid overwhelming him. If he manages that well, you could open the door to one more room tomorrow or in a few days.

Comment: Is the safe room acutally safe? How often are you in there? Are there hiding spots? Preferably high up, as cats like to be able to see what's coming from below.

Comment: @Christian yes there are many hiding spots nd high ledges in the room and I am in there watching Netflix for hours each day

Comment: The only time this is a question is if you're introducing another cat, or they're misbehaving somehow. Otherwise you are to be a good host and to accommodate your guest with w/e they want, whenever they want it. Also, "cowering in the dark corner of our bathroom" may have been mistaken for them thinking it's a good spot to hunt from.

Answer (score 14):

If your cat wants to explore the area you should let him do so, but leave the door to his safe spot open so he can hide there if or when he gets scared.

Every cat is different and some are brave and face changes head on while others are shy and need more time to feel comfortable in a new place.

Unless you have other pets there is no reason to put him in a separate room, but you should make a few safe resting places for him like a cat tree or other elevated places where he can observe the area in safety.

Comment: I'd disagree that there's no reason to keep him in a separate room; cats can get overwhelmed with changes to their "territory," so limiting the area and opening it up in stages as Elmy suggests is helpful even if he's the only pet in the house. Otherwise, this has good advice!

Comment: @AllisonC thank you for the edit.when i say no reason to put him in a separate room what i mean is a room where the door is closed and that should not be needed if one give the cat some safe hiding places.

Comment: @trondhansen we let him out of the room today and he seems to be going splendidly. Although he does seem quite a bit overwhelmed unlike last time (although he's sleeping right now) when he is awake he seems to understand that he can explore for a bit and than come right back to the safe room when he feels stressed.

Answer (score 9):

You just need to leave everything open (except main door).

He will do what he feels best, no need to tell him what to do or not to do.

I received an adult cat that was hiding most of the time in dark corners or under the furniture. So I just let him do it, he himself started progressively going out and after two weeks or so he was like a normal cat.

And now he sleeps in the bed along with my other cat.

You just need to give him time, food, water, and that's it, don't push.